# Reducing a sum of two cube roots

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I'm trying to verify that [this sum of cube roots](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pNjqHbvtXTo) is equal to 1, using `Solve`, `ToRoots`, `RootReduce`, `Expand`, restricting to $\mathbb{R}$, and so on, but am failing:

$$\sqrt[3]{8 + 3 \sqrt{21}} + \sqrt[3]{8 - 3 \sqrt{21}}$$

Even `N@...` fails to give the answer.

I can solve this by doing lots of manipulation essentially "by hand," taking care with choice of branch cuts, and so on, but I would have thought *Mathematica* could reduce such an apparently simple sum of terms, which might involve the solution to a cubic, which of course the system "knows."

Suggestions?

Comment: `CubeRoot[8 + 3 Sqrt[21]] + CubeRoot[8 - 3 Sqrt[21]] // FullSimplify`

Comment: Thanks ($+1$).  But I still wonder why the straightforward method fails to find the right branch cut.

Comment: Factor out -1 from the second cube root, so MMA does not see a negative number raised to a fractional power, as `((8 + 3 Sqrt[21])^(1/3) - (-8 + 3 Sqrt[21])^(1/3)) // RootReduce`

Comment: @LouisB:  Good idea... but that still relies on "human smarts" which makes sense here with the odd-power root, but may not in other contexts.

Comment: The standard convention is to define $a^b = \exp(b\log(a))$. And so for example $(-1)^{1/3} = \exp(\log(-1)/3) = \exp(i\pi/3) = 1/2 + i\sqrt{3}/2$. Both `CubeRoot` and `Surd` use a non-principal branch of the logarithm. This reminds me of this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5pa1AryylpM

Comment: Precisely.  My question was based on a similar video.  Now we (or at least I!) know how to cast such problems into the proper form for *Mathematica*.  (All part of my effort to supplant hand calculation with computer-based manipulation.  See here:  https://www.ted.com/talks/conrad_wolfram_teaching_kids_real_math_with_computers)

Comment: With a bit of noise...`In[30]:= ResourceFunction[
  "RadicalDenest"][(8 + 3 Sqrt[21])^(1/3) - (-8 + 3 Sqrt[21])^(1/3)]

During evaluation of In[30]:= Part::partd: Part specification 1[[1]] is longer than depth of object.

During evaluation of In[30]:= Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

Out[30]= 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Surd` to get the branch you want.

```
Surd[(8 + 3 Sqrt[21]), 3] + Surd[(8 - 3 Sqrt[21]), 3] // RootReduce
(* 1 *)
```

Comment: Oh... thanks for your quick answer ($\checkmark$).  Do you have a quick explanation why using `Surd` works while the "traditional" way chooses the wrong branch cut?

Comment: Because it's traditional in mathematics to choose the root with the smallest positive argument as the principal root. *Mathematica* conforms to this convention.

Comment: Ah... very helpful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you realy want, is solving these equations

`{z == x + y, x^3 == (8 - 3 Sqrt[21]), y^3 == (8 + 3 Sqrt[21])}`

and getting the only real solution for z.

```
list1 = List @@ 
  Reduce[{z == x + y, x^3 == (8 - 3 Sqrt[21]), 
    y^3 == (8 + 3 Sqrt[21])}, {x, y, z}, Backsubstitution -> True]

(sol1 = Flatten[{x, y, z} /. Solve[#, {x, y, z}] & /@ list1, 1] // 
    FullSimplify) // TableForm
```

[image]

```
sol1 // N // TableForm
```

[image]

```
Reduce[{z == x + y, x^3 == (8 - 3 Sqrt[21]), y^3 == (8 + 3 Sqrt[21]), 
  Element[z, Reals]}, {x, y, z}, Backsubstitution -> True]

(*   x == 1/2 (1 - Sqrt[21]) && y == 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[21]) && z == 1   *)
```